# Trouble implementing gtag in React SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gtag.js

I have attempted to implement GTag in a React SPA.

I have the following code:

*index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <% if (process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID) { %>
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID}"
    ></script>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

*gtag.jsx*

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

export default function gtag(...args) {
  window.dataLayer.push(args);
}
```

*GTag.jsx*

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import gtag from '../../utils/gtag';

export default class GTag extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.listen(location => {
      console.log(location);
      gtag('config', process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID, { page_path: location.pathname });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return children;
  }
}
```

*index.jsx* (Webpack entry point)

```js
import gtag from './utils/gtag';
// ...
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID);
```

Whenever I navigate to a page, this is logged to the console from the `console.log` statement. However, I’m not seeing any activity in the analytics console.

I have checked the minified code and the GA_TRACKING_ID variable is replaced correctly in the production build.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `Arguments` should be pushed to the `dataLayer`, not arrays. This means the spread syntax for the gtag function is not supported.

Updated *gtag.jsx*:

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

export default function gtag() {
  // The gtag dataLayer requires an actual Arguments object to be pushed.
  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-rest-params
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
```